# Process excel sheets in datafactory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I m trying to process single excel file with multiple sheets in it thru datafactory but I m not sure how to make process all sheets?
I have set this field as parameterized in the dataset but not sure how to provide it with the sheet name
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Mf4n.png)

Comment: We can not make process all sheets for now.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array variable filled with your sheet name, then use For Each activity to loop it.

1.Create a variable
[image]

2.Setting of For Each activity
[image]

3.Setting of dataset
[image]

Comment: But this makes the process to only work with fixed sheet names. It is possible I wont know the sheet names ahead of time and I would need to read them per file basis.